# Angular2 - how to start and with which IDE

Tags: angular, ide

I have used AngularJS 1.x now for a couple of months. Now I will switch to Angular2 (with TypeScript) and actually I am not sure which IDE to use.
It is also not clear for me how to compile the TypeScript Code into JavaScript - actually is this necessary?
I have read that Visual Studio Code would be a nice editor for Angular2 projects - is there a TypeScript compiler included? I would be glad for any information in this direction.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

**1) IDE**

I was wondering myself which IDE is the best suited for Angular2.

I'm a big *Sublime Text* supporter and even tho there's a Typescript plugin ... It didn't feel perfect with Typescript power.

So I tried with my second favourite editor : *Atom* (+ Typescript plugin).
Better BUT no support for auto import (maybe it has some now ?) and also, I had to wait 30s before I get any autocompletion.

Then I tried Webstorm as the company I'm currently working at has some licences. It was great and I was really happy for a month. But using an editor that is not free felt ... weird. I wouldn't use it at home for personal projects, I couldn't recommend it to other people easily. And honnestly, I'm not a super fan of Webstorm interface.

So I gave (another) try to **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)** that I didn't find so great when I first tried it few months ago. It has seriously evolved and :

- it's simple
- it's complete
     - Code
     - Debugger (remote --> super powerful)
     - Git integration
     - Plugin store
- it has great great Angular2 support
- intellisense is really awesome

I'm using it since a month and so far, I'm really happy and do not feel the need to change.

Just to help you start with good plugins, here's mine :
[image]

---

**2) Angular 2 : Discover the basics**

As you're familiar with AngularJs, I don't know how you felt about the official documentation but I couldn't learn from it. I had to follow many (different) tutorials and then I used to doc once I understood AngularJs.

With Angular2, they understood the challenge to have a great documentation and they pay attention to it since alpha version (even tho it was evolving continuously =) !).

So I'd recommend you to go on https://angular.io and simply read the doc.

It's well done and is not only for advanced user. You will find good tutorials there !

---

**3) How to use Typescript with Visual Studio Code ?**

I'd strongly recommend you to use **[angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)** for developing an Angular2 app. Not only for simplicity, but because in a community we need to have a basic starter which gives us the ability to have similar structured repo. So we can understand easily the structure of an other project.

Plus, angular-cli handles Typescript compilation for you and you don't have to deal with it in command line or from your IDE.

```
npm i -g typescript
```

(no need for typings anymore since Typescript 2.0 !)

```
npm i -g angular-cli
ng new my-super-project --style=scss
cd my-super-project
```

Then just run

```
ng serve
```

And access to your app at : http://localhost:4200

Angular-cli compiles your Typescript and even your (sccs|sass|less) files.

When you want to deploy your app :

```
ng serve --prod
```

Will also minimify JS and CSS.

---

**4) What's next ?**

Once you feel more comfortable with Angular2 in general, I'd strongly recommend you to learn (more) about

- [Redux](http://redux.js.org/)
- [RxJs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS)

And once you're familiar with those concepts, you should start playing with [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/store).

I've released an ngrx starter! For those familiar with Redux and willing to discover angular and/or ngrx it might help you get started! I'm sure it might also be a good idea to use this template as a starter for any kind of ngrx project (small, medium or even large!). I tried to describe in the Readme how to use it and there is plenty of comments into the code itself: https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-ngrx-starter

Comment: Added the extension after the  download                                                
"Angular 8 Snippets - TypeScript, Html, Angular Material, ngRx, RxJS & Flex Layout"

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, because since Angular 2 was released I am looking good freeware IDE which supports Angular 2. I will describe my experience.

### **NETBEANS**

It's very good IDE for Java and quite good for Web development. There is many features that boost your work. I installed plugin Everlaw Typescript that is maintained on github:

Plugin: https://github.com/Everlaw/nbts/releases

**Advantages**

- Typescript actions (build, run etc.) are available from project explorer.
- Plugin can build TS files on save.

**Disadvantages**

- Lack of support Angular 2, because this plugin support only typescript.
- Troubles with intelisense and syntax highlighting in angular template files and ts files.
- Lack of boilerplate templates for NG2.

### **ECLIPSE**

IMHO Eclipse with Angular2Eclipse plugin now is one of the best IDE for Angular 2 purpose. It is mature solution with many features that boost your work.

Plugin: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular2-eclipse

**Advantages**

- Integration with angular-cli
- Support for Angular2 syntax inside the component templates.
- Support for typescript files.
- Available Angular 2 boilerplate templates.

**Disadvantages**

IMHO there is no disadvantages.

If you are looking for good tutorial how to configure IDE try this

https://jaxenter.com/angular-2-intellij-netbeans-eclipse-128461.html

### **VS Code** + Angular Language Service

Since angular released language service, I've changed IDE to VS Code. I've worked on eclipse but now I think VS Code is better because is quite faster and more lighter than eclipse with angular addon.

> The Angular Language Service is a way to get completions, errors, hints, and navigation inside your Angular templates whether they are external in an HTML file or embedded in annotations/decorators in a string.

You can read more here https://angular.io/guide/language-service

If You want to install that addon, launch VS Code Quick Open (Ctrl+P), paste the following command, and press enter.

```
ext install Angular.ng-template
```

Addon page https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template

Comment: so what was the first IDE you described Advantages and Disadvantages for?

Comment: How does Angular2Eclipse compare to the Angular IDE?